# How to export the content of a listbox to a table in Access?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, listbox

I'm doing an application in C# windows Form that search for a certain text through every file of my computer and export it into a Listbox control. Now what i want to do is export the content from that list box to a new table in my Access Database. Unfortunatly, for the moment I can't find anything that does the trick. I also can't post any code in here cause it's pretty confidential.

Comment: I think you need to break the question down a little.  The scope is too broad.  Do you need help with inserting records into an Access database?  Do you need help splitting up the results in the list box so you can work with them?

Comment: You are right. What I really need to know is how to extract it into the C# code from my listbox and send it into access. I know how to create a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))                                    
{                                                                                                        
    c.Open();                                                                                            
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (@field1, @field2))
    {                                                                                                    
        foreach (ListItem item in listbox2.Items)                                                        
        {                                                                                                
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();                                                                      
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", item.Value);                                          
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", item.Text);                                           

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                                                                       
        }                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                    
}
```

For the access database you just need to replace SQL with OLEDB

Comment: Ok i'll try that thanks. Will approved as an awswer if it work